# Not readonly text boxes jQuery

Tags: jquery

Could some pls guide on how to select text boxes that are not readonly, I am using below:

```
count=count+parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(ind-1).find("input:text").not("readonly").val())
```

Comment: That's close, it just has to be `.not("[readonly]")`

Comment: Note that `val` returns the value for the first element in the collection

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you...

```
 $('input[type="text"]:not([readonly])')
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uothe262/) for a running example